# How to pass the input arguments of a function into the block body of it

Tags: javascript, razor

I'm implementing asp.net core project. In the razor view my code is like the following:

```
     @using System.Linq;

@model CSDDashboard.TempClasses.ChartListObjects
@{

    var XLabels = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.TotalReqStatus.Select(i => i.DimensionOne).ToList());
    var YValues = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.TotalReqStatus.Select(i => i.Quantity).ToList());
    ViewData["Title"] = "Pie Chart";
    //-----------------
    var XLabels1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.GrantedTimeAvg.Select(i => i.DimensionOne).ToList());
    var YValues1 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.GrantedTimeAvg.Select(i => i.Quantity).ToList());
    ViewData["Title"] = "Line Chart";
    //------------------
    var XLabels2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.GrantedPercent.Select(i => i.DimensionOne).ToList());
    var YValues2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.GrantedPercent.Select(i => i.Quantity).ToList());
    ViewData["Title"] = "Line Chart";
    //------------------
    var XLabels3 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.GrantedApiToApplicantAvg.Select(i => i.DimensionOne).ToList());
    var YValues3 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.GrantedApiToApplicantAvg.Select(i => i.Quantity).ToList());
    ViewData["Title"] = "Line Chart";
}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    @**@
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style>

        html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
            font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas id="piechart" style="width:100%; height:500px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="linechart1" style="width:100%; height:500px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="linechart2" style="width:100%; height:500px"></canvas>
    <canvas id="linechart3" style="width:100%; height:500px"></canvas>
<div class="container" style="width:100%; height:500px">
        <div class="row">
 </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                @*style="width:30%">*@
                <!-- pie chart -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
@*Pie chart eliminated*@
                    PieChartShow(XLabels,YValues,piechart);
                </script>
                <!--cell 4 row 1-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <!-- line chart -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    LineChartShow(XLabels1, YLabels1,linechart1);
                </script>
                <!--cell 1 row 2-->
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <!-- line chart -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    LineChartShow(XLabels2, YLabels2,linechart2);
                </script>
                <!--cell2 row 2-->
            </div>


            <div class="col-4">
                <!-- line chart -->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    LineChartShow(XLabels3, YLabels3,,linechart3);
                </script>
                <!--cell3 row3-->
            </div>
       </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var PieChartShow =
    $(function () {
        // var chartName = "piechart";

         //Here is where I have the problem:
        var myXLabels = arguments[0];
        var YYalues = arguments[1];
        var chartName = arguments[2];
    var ctx = document.getElementById(chartName).getContext('2d');
    var data = {
    labels: @Html.Raw(myXLabels),
    datasets: [{
    label: "API Charts",
    backgroundColor: [
    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0)',
    'rgba(0, 255, 0)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 255)',
    'rgba(192, 192, 192)',
    'rgba(255, 255, 0)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 255)'
    ],
    borderColor: [
    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 0)',
    'rgba(0, 255, 0)',
    'rgba(0, 0, 255)',
    'rgba(192, 192, 192)',
    'rgba(255, 255, 0)',
    'rgba(255, 0, 255)'
    ],
    borderWidth: 1,
    data: @Html.Raw(YValues)
    }]
    };

    var options = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
    yAxes: [{
    ticks: {
    min: 0,
    beginAtZero: true
    },
    gridLines: {
    display: true,
    color: "rgba(255,99,164,0.2)"
    }
    }],
    xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
    min: 0,
    beginAtZero: true
    },
    gridLines: {
    display: false
    }
    }]
    }
    };

    var myChart = new  Chart(ctx, {
    options: options,
    data: data,
    type:'pie'

    });
    });

    @**@
var LineChartShow = $(function () {

            var chartName = arguments[2];
            var ctx = document.getElementById(chartName).getContext('2d');
            var data = {
                labels: @Html.Raw(arguments[0]),
                @*labels: @Html.Raw(),*@
                @*labels: @Html.Raw(),*@
                datasets: [{
                    label: "API Charts",
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 0, 0)',
                        'rgba(0, 255, 0)',
                        'rgba(0, 0, 255)',
                        'rgba(192, 192, 192)',
                        'rgba(255, 255, 0)',
                        'rgba(255, 0, 255)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 0, 0)',
                        'rgba(0, 255, 0)',
                        'rgba(0, 0, 255)',
                        'rgba(192, 192, 192)',
                        'rgba(255, 255, 0)',
                        'rgba(255, 0, 255)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    data: @Html.Raw(YValues1)
            }]
            };

            var options = {
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            beginAtZero: true
                        },
                        gridLines: {
                            display: true,
                            color: "rgba(255,99,164,0.2)"
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            min: 0,
                            beginAtZero: true
                        },
                        gridLines: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    }]
                }
            };

            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                options: options,
                data: data,
                type: 'line'

            });
        });

</script>
```

In a div tag, I call PieChartShow(XLabels,YValues,piechart); and i want to pass XLabels, YValues and piechart as the input parameters of PieChartShow javascript function and the third parameter "piechart" is the related canvas id. But now my problem is myXLabels is unknown inside the block of data in the function PieChartShow. I appreciate if anyone suggests me how I can pass XLabels and YValues into PieChartShow function.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your function to

```
function PieChartShow(XLabels) {
    var ctx = document.getElementById(chartName).getContext('2d');
    var data = {
       labels: @Html.Raw(XLabels)
    }
}
```

I am not sure this is the full implementation of your function though.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now there is a message near the method : XLabels is declared but its value is never used.

Comment: As i mentioned, the function isnt doing much apart from initializing the variables ctx and data. What are you actually trying to achieve?